# Avoid repetition of rows in sqlite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, shuffle

I randomized the sequence of my questions but some of it shows up again even though the user has already answered it. I think I need an if else statement where getquestions must not equal to past questions. I still have no idea how to deal with the error

I used 
Collections.shuffle(que);

here's 2 files of my code

```
    TriviaQuestion.java

    public class TriviaQuestion extends Activity {
        private int id;
        private String question;
        private String opta;
        private String optb;
        private String optc;
        private String optd;
        private String answer;

        public TriviaQuestion(String q, String oa, String ob, String oc, String od, String ans) {

            question = q;
            opta = oa;
            optb = ob;
            optc = oc;
            optd = od;
            answer = ans;
        }

        public TriviaQuestion() {
            id = 0;
            question = "";
            opta = "";
            optb = "";
            optc = "";
            optd = "";
            answer = "";
        }

       /* public int getId() {
            return id;
        }*/

        public String getQuestion() {
            return question;
        }

        public String getOpta() {
            return opta;
        }

        public String getOptb() {
            return optb;
        }

        public String getOptc() {
            return optc;
        }

        public String getOptd() {
            return optd;
        }

        public String getAnswer() {
            return answer;
        }

        public void setId(int i) {
            id = i;
        }

        public void setQuestion(String q1) {
            question = q1;
        }

        public void setOpta(String o1) {
            opta = o1;
        }

        public void setOptb(String o2) {
            optb = o2;
        }

        public void setOptc(String o3) {
            optc = o3;
        }

        public void setOptd(String o4) {
            optd = o4;
        }

        public void setAnswer(String ans) {
            answer = ans;
        }


    }
```

and

TriviaQuizHelper.java

```
    public class TriviaQuizHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        Context context;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DATABASEQUIZ";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 17;
        private static final String TABLE_NAME = "TRIVIAQUIZ";
        private static final String UID = "_UID";
        private static final String QUESTION = "QUESTION";
        private static final String OPTA = "OPTA";
        private static final String OPTB = "OPTB";
        private static final String OPTC = "OPTC";
        private static final String OPTD = "OPTD";
        private static final String ANSWER = "ANSWER";
        private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + QUESTION + " VARCHAR(255), " + OPTA + " VARCHAR(255), " + OPTB + " VARCHAR(255), " + OPTC + " VARCHAR(255), " + OPTD + " VARCHAR(255), " + ANSWER + " VARCHAR(255));";
        private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

        public TriviaQuizHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

        }

        public void allQuestion() {
            TriviaQuestion q1 = new TriviaQuestion("Galileo was an Italian astronomer who developed?", "Telescope", "Airoplane", "Electricity", "Train", "Telescope");
            this.insert(q1);
            TriviaQuestion q2 = new TriviaQuestion("Who is the father of Geometry ?", "Aristotle", "Euclid", "Pythagoras", "Kepler", "Euclid");
            this.insert(q2);
            TriviaQuestion q3 = new TriviaQuestion("Who was known as Iron man of India ?", "Govind Ballabh Pant", "Jawaharlal Nehru", "Subhash Chandra Bose", "Sardar Vallabhbhai Patel", "Sardar Vallabhbhai Patel");
            this.insert(q3);
            TriviaQuestion q4 = new TriviaQuestion("The first woman in space was ?", "Valentina Tereshkova", "Sally Ride", "Naidia Comenci", "Tamara Press", "Valentina Tereshkova");
            this.insert(q4);
            TriviaQuestion q5 = new TriviaQuestion("Who is the Flying Sikh of India ?", "Mohinder Singh", "Joginder Singh", "Ajit Pal Singh", "Milkha singh", "Milkha singh");
            this.insert(q5);
            TriviaQuestion q6 = new TriviaQuestion("The Indian to beat the computers in mathematical wizardry is", "Ramanujam", "Rina Panigrahi", "Raja Ramanna", "Shakunthala Devi", "Shakunthala Devi");
            this.insert(q6);
            TriviaQuestion q7 = new TriviaQuestion("Who is Larry Pressler ?", "Politician", "Painter", "Actor", "Tennis player", "Politician");
            this.insert(q7);
            TriviaQuestion q8 = new TriviaQuestion("Michael Jackson is a distinguished person in the field of ?", "Pop Music", "Jounalism", "Sports", "Acting", "Pop Music");
            this.insert(q8);
            TriviaQuestion q9 = new TriviaQuestion("The first Indian to swim across English channel was ?", "V. Merchant", "P. K. Banerji", "Mihir Sen", "Arati Saha", "Mihir Sen");
            this.insert(q9);
            TriviaQuestion q10 = new TriviaQuestion("Who was the first Indian to make a movie?", "Dhundiraj Govind Phalke", " Asha Bhonsle", " Ardeshir Irani", "V. Shantaram", "Dhundiraj Govind Phalke");
            this.insert(q10);
            TriviaQuestion q11 = new TriviaQuestion("Who is known as the ' Saint of the gutters ?", "B.R.Ambedkar", "Mother Teresa", "Mahatma Gandhi", "Baba Amte", "Mother Teresa");
            this.insert(q11);
            TriviaQuestion q12 = new TriviaQuestion("Who invented the famous formula E=mc^2", "Albert Einstein", "Galilio", "Sarvesh", "Bill Gates", "Albert Einstein");
            this.insert(q12);
           TriviaQuestion q13 = new TriviaQuestion("Who is elected as president of us 2016", "Donald Trump", "Hilary Clinton", "Jhon pol", "Barack Obama", "Donald Trump");
            this.insert(q13);
            TriviaQuestion q14 = new TriviaQuestion("Who was the founder of company Microsoft", "Bill Gates", "Bill Clinton", "Jhon rio", "Steve jobs", "Bill Gates");
            this.insert(q14);
            TriviaQuestion q15 = new TriviaQuestion("Who was the founder of company Apple ?", "Steve Jobs", "Steve Washinton", "Bill Gates", "Jobs Wills", "Steve Jobs");
            this.insert(q15);
            TriviaQuestion q16 = new TriviaQuestion("Who was the founder of company Google ?", "Steve Jobs", "Bill Gates", "Larry Page", "Sundar Pichai", "Larry Page");
            this.insert(q16);
            TriviaQuestion q17 = new TriviaQuestion("Who is know as god of cricket ?", "Sachin Tendulkar", "Kapil Dev", "Virat Koli", "Dhoni", "Sachin Tendulkar");
            this.insert(q17);
            TriviaQuestion q18 = new TriviaQuestion("who has won ballon d'or of 2015 ?", "Lionel Messi", "Cristiano Ronaldo", "Neymar", "Kaka", "Lionel Messi");
            this.insert(q18);
            TriviaQuestion q19 = new TriviaQuestion("who has won ballon d'or of 2014 ?", "Neymar", "Lionel Messi", "Cristiano Ronaldo", "Kaka", "Cristiano Ronaldo");
            this.insert(q19);
            TriviaQuestion q20 = new TriviaQuestion("the Founder of the most famous gaming platform steam is ?", "Bill Cliton", "Bill Williams", "Gabe Newell", "Bill Gates", "Gabe Newell");
            this.insert(q20);
        }
        public void insert(TriviaQuestion triviaQuestion) {
            ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();
           /* contentvalues.put(UID,triviaQuestion.getId());*/
            contentvalues.put(QUESTION, triviaQuestion.getQuestion());
            contentvalues.put(OPTA, triviaQuestion.getOpta());
            contentvalues.put(OPTB, triviaQuestion.getOptb());
            contentvalues.put(OPTC, triviaQuestion.getOptc());
            contentvalues.put(OPTD, triviaQuestion.getOptd());
            contentvalues.put(ANSWER, triviaQuestion.getAnswer());
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentvalues);
        }
        public List<TriviaQuestion> getAllQuestion() {
            List<TriviaQuestion> que = new ArrayList<>();
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String coloumns[] = {UID, QUESTION, OPTA, OPTB, OPTC, OPTD, ANSWER};
            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, coloumns, null, null, null, null, null);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                TriviaQuestion triviaQuestion = new TriviaQuestion();
                triviaQuestion.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                triviaQuestion.setQuestion(cursor.getString(1));
                triviaQuestion.setOpta(cursor.getString(2));
                triviaQuestion.setOptb(cursor.getString(3));
                triviaQuestion.setOptc(cursor.getString(4));
                triviaQuestion.setOptd(cursor.getString(5));
                triviaQuestion.setAnswer(cursor.getString(6));
                que.add(triviaQuestion);
                //here is the culprit, lol:
                Collections.shuffle(que);
            }
            return que;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suspect you called `allQuestion()` more than once in the lifetime of the app and have duplicates in your db. SQLite does not repeat rows by itself.

Comment: Offtopic: move `Collections.shuffle()` out from the loop, you are calling it many times. It's not needed. And close the cursor after using.

Comment: where will I move it

Comment: after the while loop, i.e. after the `}` and before `return que;`. That's also the place where you should put `cursor.close();`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
db.insertWithOnConflict(table, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: where will I insert it

Comment: When you are inserting the data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a set called `unansweredQuestions` and another called `answeredQuestions`. You could store all your questions in `unansweredQuestions` initially and whenever a question is answered, move it to `answeredQuestions`. If you randomize `unansweredQuestions` without the answered questions, you will have your desired behavior.

Alternatively you could shuffle the set of questions and always store the index of the last answered question and read the question just after that.